# How to get a column total in a Winforms Pivot Grid control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I need to display the percentage of each cell, of a pivot grid, column against its column total.

So far, I have been checking possible ways to get the columns totals being displayed by the PivotGrid (as I already know [how to insert a computed column using expressions](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument6230)) but so far I haven't found a place where these values are available.

I have also considered to handle the CustomSummary or CustomUnboundFieldData events of the PivotGrid but I don't see clearly how can I get the column total from there.

Another approach I have think of is to try to use the [PivotCellBaseEventArgs.CreateDrillDownDataSource](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1884) to get the underlying records of the cell, but then I will not be able to get the column total, as the records returned by that method are only for a specific cell, not for the whole column.

I'll appreciate if you can point out what would be the best approach for dealing with the cell percentage against column total requirement, including any of the previous or maybe another approach I haven't think of.

Also I will be glad if you show me a way of getting the column total from the pivot grid control, if there's any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the way to do this so I am posting it in case anyone else need it...

There is a property on a PivotGridField that allows you to control the way the data is "summarized" (i.e. aggregated). Usually this is set to "as is" or Default but you can change this to support what is called [Percentage Modes](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument10914).

So I just change the PivotSummaryDisplayType, of the field that I wanted to display as percentage, to PivotSummaryDisplayType.PercentOfColumnGrandTotal and that's it.